# How to adjust x labels in R boxplot

Tags: r, boxplot

This is my code to create a boxplot in R that has 4 boxplots in one.

```
psnr_x265_256 <- c(39.998,39.998, 40.766, 38.507,38.224,40.666,38.329,40.218,44.746,38.222)
psnr_x264_256 <- c(39.653, 38.106,37.794,36.13,36.808,41.991,36.718,39.26,46.071,36.677)
psnr_xvid_256 <- c(33.04564,33.207269,32.715427,32.104696,30.445141,33.135261,32.669766, 31.657039,31.53103,31.585865)
psnr_mpeg2_256 <- c(32.4198,32.055051,31.424819,30.560274,30.740421,32.484694, 32.512268,32.04659,32.345848, 31)

all_errors = cbind(psnr_x265_256, psnr_x264_256, psnr_xvid_256,psnr_mpeg2_256)
modes = cbind(rep("PSNR",10))

journal_linear_data <-data.frame(psnr_x265_256, psnr_x264_256, psnr_xvid_256,psnr_mpeg2_256)

yvars <- c("psnr_x265_256","psnr_x264_256","psnr_xvid_256","psnr_mpeg2_256")
xvars <- c("x265","x264","xvid","mpeg2")

bmp(filename="boxplot_PSNR_256.bmp")

boxplot(journal_linear_data[,yvars], xlab=xvars, ylab="PSNR")

dev.off()
```

This is the image I get.

[image]

I want to have the corresponding values for each boxplot in x axis `"x265","x264","xvid","mpeg2"`.

Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: `boxplot(journal_linear_data[,yvars], ylab="PSNR", names = xvars)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways of changing the labels for your boxplot variables. Probably the simplest way is changing the column names of your data frame:

```
colnames(journal_linear_data) <- c("x265","x264","xvid","mpeg2")
```

Even simpler: you could do this right at the creation of your data frame too:

```
journal_linear_data <- data.frame(x265=psnr_x265_256, x264=psnr_x264_256, xvid=psnr_xvid_256, mpeg2=psnr_mpeg2_256)
```

If you run into the problem of your labels not being shown or overlapping due to too few space, try rotating the x labels using the `las` parameter, e.g. `las=2` or `las=3`.